# Can I dynamically pass a class into another class in swfit?

Tags: swift

Hi I am new to `Swift` and I am asked to follow a project. Now I have two classes, one is called `DrinkCostBehavior` that conforms to a `protocol` called `TabBehavior`

Now I want to reuse the `BeerCostBehavior` for some other drink like wine and coke.

The project structure is based on an ongoing one, I cannot do much about it.

```
struct DrinkLinkViewModel: LinkViewModel {

    let title: String? = "Drink"

    let linkRowViewModels: [LinkRowViewModel] = [
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Beer",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Coke",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Wine",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        )
    ]
}
```

In the `LinkRowViewModel`, I want to pass hardcoded data `viewModel` into it. Such as

```
  LinkRowViewModel(
                title: "Wine",
                behavior: DrinkCostBehavior(instanceOfWineViewModel)
            )
```

I tried to create an instance of WineViewModel and pass into `DrinkCostBehavior`, and initialize   and assign it in `DrinkCostBehavior` but it returns an error of `Property Initializers Run Before 'self' Is Available`

```
class DrinkCostBehavior: TapBehavior {

    private let wineViewModel: DrinkViewModel

    init(test: DrinkViewModel) {
        self.wineViewModel = test
    }

    func onDidTap(viewController: UIViewController?) {
        // Function that navigates user when the view is clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in DrinkCostBehavior class replace this *init* method

```
init(test: DrinkViewModel) {
    self.wineViewModel = test
}
```

`self.wineViewModel = wineViewModel`  this wineViewModel initialize with same object so it gives error

Comment: That's a typo when I test it myself, changed to `test` and still don't fix it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance of `DrinkViewModel` like this:

```swift
let instanceOfWineViewModel = DrinkViewModel()

struct DrinkLinkViewModel: LinkViewModel {

    let title: String? = "Drink"

    let linkRowViewModels: [LinkRowViewModel] = [
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Beer",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Coke",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Wine",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior(instanceOfWineViewModel)
        )
    ]
}
```

You should do:

```swift
struct DrinkLinkViewModel: LinkViewModel {

    let title: String? = "Drink"

    let linkRowViewModels: [LinkRowViewModel]
}

let instanceOfWineViewModel = DrinkViewModel()

let drinkLinkViewModel = DrinkLinkViewModel(
    linkRowViewModels: [
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Beer",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Coke",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior()
        ),
        LinkRowViewModel(
            title: "Wine",
            behavior: DrinkCostBehavior(test: instanceOfWineViewModel)
        )
    ]
)
```